# How to check query parameter in url using Regex in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to check if below two regex are matching

Target Url: **/challenge/getAllChallenges?type=public**

Regex: **"/challenge/getAllChallenges([/?]+)"**

But seems like above Regex only allows any character to appear after "getAllChallenge"

How do I allow only '?' as the first character to appear after "getAllChallenge"?

ideally both of below url to be validated as a match through a single regex:

- /challenge/getAllChallenges
- /challenge/getAllChallenges?type=public

but below to be not valid

- /challenge/getAllChallenge/blah
- /challenge/getAllChallengeblah

Comment: Why Regex? Have you considered using the [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0) class instead?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
/challenge/getAllChallenges(\?[^?]+)?$
```

It's "/challenge/getAllChallenges" followed by zero or one of: (question mark followed by one or more of anything other than question mark)

Your original regex required "/challenge/getAllChallenges" followed by one or more of: (forward slash, question mark)

Special characters lose their meaning inside `[]` character classes, and hence do not need escaping (if that's what you were trying to do by putting a slash before the `?` (which if you were, the slash was the wrong direction; backslash escapes, not forward slash))

It would be important to include the end of input marker `$` to prevent a partial match reporting a success

-

I support the notion raised in the comment: generally using a class dedicated to parsing and manipulating a kind of value will give better results than a regex based solution. For example the regex I gave above is in response to what was determined from your required matches - either no ? or ?-followed-by-something but a url that simply ends with a question mark is perfectly valid, but the regex will need tweaking to allow it